# Why the exact date of Laylat al-Qadr (night of power) is not specified?

Tags: ramadan, laylat-al-qadr

*Why the exact date of Laylat al-Qadr is not specified in Islamic resources ?*

I hear that people say the reason is to fill the last 10 odd nights with ibadah. But I think if it was so, Islam could just ask people for ibadah in those nights *for other reasons* instead.  I think there should be something deep about this uncertainty of Laylat al-Qadr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the night of power (laylat al-qadr) fixed?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2078/59)

Comment: check this urdu book really short.
http://www.szic.edu.pk/images/stories/publications/2013/july/lailatulqadar-szic-publications.pdf

Comment: may be because people will pray only at that perticular night and will not give much importance to other days.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is quite some logic in the fact that the exact night isn't revealed. Laylatul Qadr also known as the 'night of power' is said to be better than a 1000 months.

With its exact date not being known to us, we concentrate our efforts into the last 10 days in which we reap the benefits of the blessed month of Ramadan which in itself is a month like no other in terms of reward and benefit. It teaches us steadfastness if we concentrate our efforts over a longer period of time such as the last 10 days, if not the whole month, than if we were to know the exact day in which case we would exuberate all our efforts into 1 day.

We underestimate the lessons learnt from steadfastness, and we pray that Allah grant us this in our efforts instead of the peaks and troughs we see in our own and other's deen.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know when Laylatul-Qadr is, because the Prophet Muhammad (S.A) got interrupted as he was about to say. Here's the story:

Someone asked the prophet, "When *is* Laylatul-Qadr?" And the prophet replied, " It is –"
As he was about to reply, somebody or something interrupted them. It was not specified, the date of Laylatul-Qadr. But yes, we were told to look in the last ten days of Ramadan. Odd dates, that it.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, for Muslims, if you pray in this one day alone, yes, it's equal to the praying of *84* years! That's a lifetime long. Make sure you pray a lot when Laylatul-Qadr's announced. We should value this day; thanks to the blessed Prophet, we pray 5 salah, but it's equal to 50 salah, the original amount of prayer we would do if the Prophet Muhammad (S.A) didn't meet Allah (S.W.T).